# Observable.of mock interface implementation from jest-mock-extend doen't fire

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs-observables, jest-mock-extended

By writing complex mocks I realized, that an Observable.of mock interface implementation with jest-mock-extend doesn't fire. The following test fail with timeout, cause the Observable never fires.

```
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

interface TestInterface {
  dummyProperty: string;
}

describe( 'Test Observable.of mock interface implementation', () => {
  it( 'test Observable of an Interface mock', (done) => {
    const mockTestInterface = mock<TestInterface>();

    of( mockTestInterface ).subscribe( testObject => {
      expect( testObject ).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    })
  })
})
```

What I'm doing wrong, or overseeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import { mock, JestMockExtended } from 'jest-mock-extended';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

interface TestInterface {
  dummyProperty: string;
}

describe('Test Observable.of mock interface implementation', () => {
  it('test Observable of an Interface mock', (done) => {
    JestMockExtended.configure({ ignoreProps: ['schedule'] });
    const mockTestInterface = mock<TestInterface>();
    of(mockTestInterface).subscribe((testObject) => {
      expect(testObject).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

package versions:

```json
"rxjs": "^6.5.4",
"jest-mock-extended": "^2.0.7",
"jest": "^28.1.3",
```